# Open MS Access form with matching AutoID from another form

Tags: ms-access, macros, openform

I have two forms, one is a *member entry* form and the other is a *volunteer* form. The member form can be navigated through to specific numbers then edited. I placed a linking button to make it easy to setup the particular individual to be a volunteer (so it opens the volunteer form). I would like the volunteer form to show the exact matching `AutoID` record that is in the member form (because having all those fields on one form is too much clutter). It is basically another part of the member form. How would I set up the macro to find the form I am on with `AutoID`?
How would I write the code or set it up from the macro form? I have tried a `where` statement from the active form to be in the new open form but the code is not agreeing.

To put it another way:

- `MemberForm` is form1 (with field `AutoID` since it comes from the same table)
- `VolunteerForm` is the opening form (with field `AutoID`)

We just want to change the opening value on the `AutoID`.

Comment: You could use a subform with a master-child link, or the BrowseTo macro action, or write a query where the ID is passed as a parameter, or a few other ways - Access is pretty flexible in that regard!

Comment: send the auto_id as "openArgs" to subform.. or put a tab control in your main form and put the subfom in the second tab???

Answer (score 0):

This link to a video answered my question:
https://youtu.be/RILqSTAAQpM

Basically when you make the open form button choose to, "open the form and find specific data to display." This option will allow you to link a related primary key field to the opening records.